# Automated Android device setup and app deployment

Tags: android, deployment, mdm

Other than using an MDM service or product, is there a way to automate the mass setup of android devices that all need the same configuration?

Requirements:

- APK installation (in-house app)
- Profile setup (lockscreen setup, screen brightness, etc.)
- Customization (wallpaper, icon placement, removal of unwanted default apps)

Comment: Yes. you can cook your own ROM and flash all devices.

Comment: @zaitsman Any idea if there is a guide on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I am only familiar with Samsung solutions.

For exactly this purpose Knox Configure has been created. You can setting up big bunch of phones without even opening the boxes.

So if you use Android Samsung devices take a look:

https://www.samsungknox.com/en/solutions/knox-configure

Update: Google introduced Zero Touch with Android Oreo

https://www.android.com/enterprise/management/zero-touch/